# How to overwrite defined? operator?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, constants

if you have something like:

```
module Real
  A = 1
end
```

when you do `defined?(Real::A)` you get 'constant' which is a truish value. Now if i do something like:

```
module Virtual
  def self.constants
    [:A] + super
  end
  def self.const_missing(sym)
    return 1 if sym == :A
    super
  end
  def self.const_defined?(sym)
    return true if sym == :A
    super
  end
end
```

`defined?(Virtual::A)` return nil. Is there some way to overwrite defined? behaviour to take metaprogrammed constants into acccount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defined?` is actually an operator (and not just syntactic sugar like `+`) and as such cannot be redefined. The proper solution would be to not use `defined?` for checking but aforementioned `const_defined?`. `defined?` isn't intended for meta-programming and works on the parser level, which is why it can give rather detailed information on the type of expression.